# only one database create while using a multi-database setup

Tags: database, django, router, django-celery

I am trying to setup celery in one of my django projects. I want celery to use a separate database. Currently, as the project is in development phase we are using sqlite3. In order to setup multiple databases i did the following.

#### Defined databases in the settings.py file.

```
DATABASES = {'default':
                {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                 'NAME':'devel',
                 'USER':'',
                 'PASSWORD':'',
                 'HOST':'',
                 'PORT':'',
                 },  
             'celery':
                {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
                 'NAME':'celery',
                 'USER':'',
                 'PASSWORD':'',
                 'HOST':'',
                 'PORT':'',
                },  
}
```

#### Created a Router Object in db_routers.py file

```
class CeleryRouter(object):
    """
    This class will route all celery related models to a»
    separate database.
    """

    # Define the applications to be used in the celery database
    APPS = (
        'django',
        'djcelery'
    )

    # Define Database Alias
    DB = 'celery'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point read operations to celery database.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.DB
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Point write operations to celery database.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return self.DB
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow any relation between two objects in the db pool
        """
        if (obj1._meta.app_label is self.APPS) and \
           (obj2._meta.app_label in self.APPS):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """
        Make sure the celery tables appear only in celery
        database.
        """
        if db == self.DB:
            return model._meta.app_label in self.APPS
        elif model._meta.app_label in self.APPS:
            return False
        return None
```

#### Updated the `DATABASE_ROUTER` variable in settings.py file

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'appname.db_routers.CeleryRouter',
]
```

Now, when i do `python manage.py syncdb` i see that the tables are created for celery but there is only one database created i.e. `devel`. Why are the tables being created in the `devel` database and not in `celery` database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/):

> The syncdb management command operates on one database at a time. By default, it operates on the default database, but by providing a --database argument, you can tell syncdb to synchronize a different database.

Try running:

```
./manage.py syncdb --database=celery
```

Comment: That works. So this means we'll explicitly need to run `syncdb` for each database ?